# Is it possible to create a program that accepts 3 integers and outputs the odd/even integers without using array?

Tags: c

Our teacher gave us an exercise in C. We have to create a program that accepts three integers and outputs them if they are odd or even without using arrays, only loops and conditional statements can be used.
What I am only allowed to use are scanf(), printf(), loops and conditional statements. I must not have multiple variables like odd1, odd2, odd3, even1, even2, even3.And I must not do scanf("%d %d %d",), so I must run scanf("%d") three times in a loop.I couldn't think of any idea that would precisely print the same format of the expected output. I hope someone could help me on this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int i, num;

    printf("Enter three integers: ");

    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &num);

          if(!(num%2))
          {
            printf("\nEven: %d", num);    
          }
          if(num%2)
          {
            printf("\nOdd: %d\n", num);    
          }
    }
}
```

I expect the following like this...

Input:

```
   1 2 3
```

Output:

```
   Odd: 1 3
   Even: 2
```

Input:

```
   2 4 6
```

Output:

```
   Odd:  
   Even: 2 4 6
```

...but the only thing i can do is this

Input:

```
   1 2 3
```

Output:

```
    Odd: 1
   Even: 2
    Odd: 3
```

Input:

```
    1 3 5
```

Output:

```
    Odd: 1
    Odd: 3
    Odd: 5
```

Comment: @KenY-N , It is what I did too, sir. But the teacher didn''t accept that code. For me, it seems impossible.

Comment: run your loop twice. First pick odd numbers then even numbers.

Comment: I assume writing to strings would be cheating as they're character arrays.

Comment: @Mike You have to store those numbers somewhere. `stdin` can't be reliably rewound.

Comment: @Schwern hi ,sir. I'd like to hear your idea. I can somehow substitute character arrays with putchar or printf

Comment: it seems from your description that it is ok with having three integer variables instead one? scanf("%d %d %d", &n1,&n2,&n3) ...

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Are you aware that you are not asking a question? In either case, start with two integers.

Comment: @Anders,I have tried it already, sir, but the teacher won't accept it. I must run the scanf("%d", &num) three times in a loop.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, hello, sir. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean (approximately) what I wrote. You'll have to be a bit more specific with your question if you want me to clarify something.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have updated the description already,sir. thanks

Comment: Tell your teacher that it would be more meaningful to teach you program **with** arrays than **without** them.

Comment: And your program uses **4** arrays (of char).

Answer (score 4):

Recursion (loop in disguise) for the win (if you don't mind having the even numbers reversed).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void separate(int m, int n) {
    if (m == n) printf("Odd:");
    if (n == 0) { printf("\nEven:"); return; }
    int i;
    if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    // print odd numbers before recursing; even numbers after recursing
    if (i % 2 == 1) printf(" %d", i);
    separate(m, n - 1);
    if (i % 2 == 0) printf(" %d", i);

    if (m == n) printf("\n\n");
}
```

See https://ideone.com/GpE7rC which includes the calling and input

```
separate(3, 3); // for 3 numbers
```

Comment: i hope it will print "odd: " before scanning all the 3 numbers

Comment: That's an easy change, @AjithCNarayanan. The core of my answer is in printing the numbers **before** or **after** the recursive call. Have fun! *I just wanted to cram it all in one single function, moving functionality out of the recursive function makes it simpler :)*

Comment: I think this is the only answer that satisfies the requirements, although I wonder if it is too advanced for OP. I'd love to see what answer the teacher had in mind.

Comment: It still uses arrays.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: no array version, recursive function simplified at https://ideone.com/6ik1XB

Comment: A bounty worthy answer :)))

Answer (score 0):

One way would be say:

```
int odd1, odd2, odd3, numOdd = 0; 

/* Code as above */

scanf("%d", &num);

if (num%2)
{
    if (numOdd == 0)
    {
        odd1 = num;
        numOdd++;
    }
    else if (numOdd == 1)
    {
        odd2 = num;
        numOdd++;
    }
    /* And continue */
}
else
{
    /* Repeat with even1, even2, even3 and numEven */
}

/* Print out numOdd oddn's */
/* Print out numEven evenn's */
```

It seems a silly exercise, but at least you'll get a lot of practise writing `if` statements...

---

I also thought:

```
scanf("%d", &num1);
scanf("%d", &num2);
scanf("%d", &num3);
```

Might be shorter, but then you don't need a for loop, unless you do something like:

```
printf("Odd: ");
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    int thisNum;
    if (i == 0) thisNum = num1;
    else if (i == 1) thisNum = num2;
    /* etc */
    if (thisNum % 2) printf("%d ", thisNum);
}
```

Comment: Per the OPs question, cannot use multiple variables.  see: *I must not have multiple variables like odd1, odd2, odd3, even1, even2, even3.*

Answer (score 0):

The problems is that you cannot use arrays. Hence you must not use strings, which are arrays. Allowing the use of `scanf` and `printf` is a deliberate trap set by your teacher - there is no way of using them in an useful way without resorting to use of arrays, explicit or implied.

Therefore you must do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


void print_number(int n)
{
    if (n < 0) {
        putchar('-');
        n = -n;
    }

    if (n == 0)
        putchar('0');

    if (n / 10)
        print_number(n / 10);

    putchar(n % 10 + '0');
}

int main(void) {
    putchar('E');
    putchar('n');
    putchar('t');
    putchar('e');
    putchar('r');
    putchar(' ');
    putchar('t');
    putchar('h');
    putchar('r');
    putchar('e');
    putchar('e');
    putchar(' ');
    putchar('i');
    putchar('n');
    putchar('t');
    putchar('e');
    putchar('g');
    putchar('e');
    putchar('r');
    putchar('s');
    putchar(':');
    putchar(' ');
    fflush(stdout);

    int odd1, odd2, odd3, odd_count = 0;
    int even1, even2, even3, even_count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int number = 0;
        int c;
        while (1) {
            c = getchar();
            if (isspace(c)) {
                if (c == '\n')
                    break;

                while ((c = getchar()) == ' ');
                ungetc(c, stdin);
                break;
            }
            else if (isdigit(c)) {
                number = number * 10 + c - '0';
            }
        }
        if (number % 2) {
            switch (odd_count) {
                case 0: odd1 = number; break;
                case 1: odd2 = number; break;
                case 2: odd3 = number; break;
            }
            odd_count ++;
        }
        else {
            switch (even_count) {
                case 0: even1 = number; break;
                case 1: even2 = number; break;
                case 2: even3 = number; break;
            }
            even_count ++;
        }
    }

    putchar('O');
    putchar('d');
    putchar('d');
    putchar(':');
    putchar(' ');

    if (odd_count >= 1) {
        print_number(odd1);
    }

    if (odd_count >= 2) {
        putchar(' ');
        print_number(odd2);
    }

    if (odd_count >= 3) {
        putchar(' ');
        print_number(odd3);
    }

    putchar('\n');
    putchar('E');
    putchar('v');
    putchar('e');
    putchar('n');
    putchar(':');
    putchar(' ');

    if (even_count >= 1) {
        print_number(even1);
    }

    if (even_count >= 2) {
        putchar(' ');
        print_number(even2);
    }

    if (even_count >= 3) {
        putchar(' ');
        print_number(even3);
    }

    putchar('\n');
}
```

This code does not use any arrays.

If you cannot define any functions (other than `main` obviously), you must inline the `print_number` in the 6 places changing the recursion into iteration. Good luck!

If the teacher however accepts the use of strings in a task that does not allow the use of arrays, you can take it as a license to disregard all silly restrictions set by them.

Comment: Per the OPs question, cannot use multiple variables.  see: *I must not have multiple variables like odd1, odd2, odd3, even1, even2, even3.*

Comment: You should cast the argument of `is*()` functions: `isdigit((unsigned char)c)` :)

Comment: Haha but I needn't :)) it's a trap

Answer (score -3):

Given the fact that you are learning C, perhaps your teacher wants to teach you some pointer arithmetics instead of using arrays like in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  int *odd = (int*)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
  int odd_count = 0;
  int *even = (int*)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
  int even_count = 0;

  printf("Enter three integers: ");

  for(i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    int num = 0;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if(!(num%2))
    {
        *even++ = num;
        even_count++;
    }
    if(num%2)
    {
        *odd++ = num;
        odd_count++;
    }
  }

  even -= even_count;
  odd -= odd_count;

  printf("\nEven: ");
  for(i=0; i<even_count; i++)
  {
     printf("%d ", *even++);
  }

  printf("\nOdd: ");
  for(i=0; i<odd_count; i++)
  {
     printf("%d ", *odd++);
  }

  free(odd);
  free(even);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well that is still using arrays, just dynamically allocated ones. and `3` is not the right argument for `malloc`

Comment: There's no need to cast `malloc()` in C. Also, you pass bad pointers to `free()`.

Comment: Sorry, sir. but we are not allowed to use pointers or malloc functions